# MYSQL retorna filas repetidas cuando hago SELECT de tablas relacionadas

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Mi duda es la siguiente.

Tengo una tabla productos y otra negocios, entablé una relación entre las dos, donde muchos productos pueden pertenecer a un negocio, y un negocio puede tener muchos productos. La clave foránea id_biz ( de la tabla productos ) hace referencia al ID de la tabla Negocios. Ahora cuando hago el SELECT para obtener todos los productos que correspondan a un negocio con ID 4, MYSQL me retorna filas repetidas. Es decir: Hago esto.

```
SELECT * FROM business b INNER JOIN products p ON b.id = p.id_biz;
```

Y me retorna esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quiero obtener es que, me muestre solo 1 Negocio, y luego los 4 productos correspondientes a ese Negocio, no que me repita la fila del Negocio ID 4, no se si me explico.

Comment: Lo que me creo que estás solicitando (corrígeme sino) es ver cada uno de los negocios y luego 4 columnas distintas para los cuatro productos relacionados con el mismo. Si es esto, no es algo trivial, y además suele ser una mala forma de visualizar la información, ¿que ocurre si tienes negocios con 100 productos por ejemplo?

Comment: Lo que intento hacer es: que me muestre toda la información de 1 Negocio y luego me muestre toda la información de todos los productos que se asocien con 1 Negocio. Lo que me devuelve en la imagen de arriba son los 4 productos asociados a un Negocio, pero me muestra 4 veces el mismo Negocio.

Comment: Es que efectivamente así es como se muestra la información en cualquier base de datos relacional, tienes una fila de una tabla que se relaciona con cuatro de otra, como hay que mostrar esas 4 filas y respetar una salida "rectangular", se repite 4 veces la fila única de la primer tabla. Esto es lo básico de cualquier base de datos, si quieres mostrar los datos de otra forma, debes elaborar algún tipo de reporte con alguna herramienta específica.

Comment: Imagino entonces que lo que estás buscando es ver solo una vez los datos de la primer tabla, por ejemplo en la primer fila y el resto de las filas y columnas que muestre `NULL`, eso se puede lograr con SQL plano, pero es una complejidad innecesaria, esto debiera elaborarse con alguna herramienta de reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta que tu propones es un producto cartesiano, por lo tanto, te devuelve un registro por cada producto que un negocio tenga registrado, es decir, si un negocio tiene 4 productos registrados como resultado de la consulta tendrás 4 registros con diferente producto pero con el mismo negocio.

Deduzco que tu duda radica en, como puedo mostrar en un solo campo el nombre de los productos que tiene un negocio sin la necesidad de mostrar un registro por cada producto y mejor mostrar un registro por negocio y en un campo la lista de todos sus productos concatenados.

Como no conozco la estructura de tus tablas involucradas, te dejo un ejemplo para que lo retomes y lo adaptes de acuerdo a lo que requieres:

```
SELECT b.name AS nombreNegocio, 
 STUFF(
    (SELECT ', '  + p.name
    FROM products AS p
    INNER JOIN business AS b ON b.id = p.id_biz
    FOR XML PATH('')),
    1, 2, '') AS nombreProductos
FROM business;
```

La anterior consulta lo que hace es buscar los productos que tiene un negocio a través de una subconsulta y los va concatenando en un solo campo, el cual lo nombro con un alias como "nombreProductos". Usamos la función STUFF para eliminar la primera coma de la concatenación. Al final tu consulta debería devolver algo como:

- negocio1       coca cola, pan, galletas
- negocio2       coca cola, jugo

Comment: Muchísimas gracias! es una buena manera de lograr lo que quería!

Answer (score 1):

Te falta especificar el `where` y asignarle un alias a las tablas con `as`:

```
SELECT * FROM business as b INNER JOIN products as p ON b.id = p.id_biz where = b.id = 1;
```

Comment: El tema es que no usaría el where, porque yo quiero obtener todos los negocios y sus respectivos productos, es decir, no quiero seleccionar uno en particular ¿me explico? el único problema es que me da la tabla de negocios repetidas en base a cuantos registros tengo en la tabla productos.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM business as b INNER JOIN products as p ON b.id = p.id_biz ;` Intenta esto, y me cuentas..

Comment: Da el mismo efecto que la imagen. Me retorna 4 rows, 1 es el negocio y los otros 3 los productos. El tema es que si quiero imprimir esa información, voy a tener la información del Negocio duplicada por 4.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM business as b INNER JOIN products as p ON b.id = p.id_biz ;`

Answer (score 1):

Yo prefiero hacer las relaciones así:

```
select * from business b, products p where b.id=p.biz
```

Comment: Es buena opción pero me da el mismo resultado, me repite los registros del Negocio dependiendo cuantos registros tenga en productos asociados a ese negocio.

Comment: Con eso no debería, lo más probable es que tengas registros duplicados en products, si puedes incluye un pantallazo

Comment: Lo que tengo en producto son 3 registros con ID única y lo único que coincide es el id_biz que hace referencia a un Negocio de la tabla business.