# ¿Como hago esta consultas multitabla en mysql?

Tags: mysqli

esta es mi duda.
Tengo 3 tablas (USERS,COMENTARIOS,RESPUESTAS). Lo que basicamente quiero es traerme los comentarios de un posts con sus respuestas pero con los datos del usuario para cada comentario y cada respuesta.

los campos de las tablas son los siguientes USERS(id,username,img_perfil), COMENTARIOS(id,comentario,id_user,id_post), RESPUESTAS(id,respuesta,id_comentario,id_user)

tengo la siguiente sql

```
SELECT 
comentarios.id,
comentarios.id_user,
comentarios.comentario,
users.id as id_user,
users.username,
users.img_user,
respuestas.id,
respuestas.respuesta,
respuestas.id_user,
respuestas.id_comentario
INNER JOIN users ON users.id = comentarios.id_user 
LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario= comentarios.id
WHERE comentarios.id_post=1
```

Pero no me da, lo que quiero es una sql que me devuelva las los comentarios con sus respuestas y el usuario y su imagen de perfil de cada comentario y respuesta.
Ojala me puedan ayudar un poquito con esto estoy medio enredado.

Mas o menos quiero obtener los datos de la siguiente manera.

id.comentario----comentario--user.comentario--img_user.comentario----id.respuesta---respuesta---user.respuesta--- img_user.respuesta...

por cada fila.
Con un left join logro consegui los comentarios con sus repsuesta mi duda esta mas en como  incluir los usuarios de los comentarios y de la respuesta en la misma fila.

Las relaciones seria de 1 a 1  comentarios/users , 1 a 1 respuestas/users, 1 a muchos comentarios/respuestas

Edito el post para decir que encontre la solocuion a mi problema.
Viendo un video en youtube sobre consultas avanzadas encontre la forma de hacerlo para los que se encuentran en la misma situacion yo lo resolvi de laseguiente forma.

```
SELECT comentarios.id, comentarios.id_user, comentarios.comentario, respuestas.id, respuestas.respuesta, respuestas.id_user, respuestas.id_comentario, usersc.id,usersc.username as user_c,usersc.img_user as img_user_c, usersr.id,usersc.username as user_r,usersr.img_user as img_user_r FROM comentarios LEFT JOIN respuestas ON respuestas.id_comentario = comentarios.id  LEFT JOIN users as usersc ON comentarios.id_user=usersc.id LEFT JOIN users as usersr ON respuestas.id_user=usersr.id WHERE comentarios.id_post=3
```

la clave esta en ahcer otros left join para cada caso  usando AS para referenciar la tabla con un nombre distinto en cada caso miren la sql y se van a dar cuenta.

Gracais a todos igual por responder.

Comment: Pero, ¿cómo quieres los datos? Puede que en este caso te convenga usar `GROUP_CONCAT` para organizar los comentarios por usuario o para organizar las respuestas seguidas de sus comentarios y los autores de los mismos, según los requerimientos.

Comment: necesitos los comentarios y sus repsuestas pero en la misma fila quiero el usuario del comentario y el usuario de la respuesta  me entedes?

Comment: Más o menos. Como te decía, si quieres eso en una sola fila, tienes que usar `GROUP_CONCAT` con un separador combinándolo con `GROUP BY`, así traes todo en una sola fila y luego por programación puedes distribuir la presentación de los datos. De todos modos faltan detalles en tu pregunta: ¿cómo se relacionan las tablas? y ayudaría que pongas un ejemplo breve de cómo quieres los resultados.

Comment: okey voy a editar creo que las relaciones estan bastante claras se relacionan por la llave foranea id_nombredelatabla relacionada

Comment: Creo que ayudaría para que te podamos entender que preparasen un sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) con las tablas y algunos datos, y finalmente escribieses el resultado esperado de la consulta

Comment: Creo que esta claro que necesito incluir el usuario del comentario y de la respuesta en cada fila.  Pero  no se como hacerlo es eso basicamente. Todo lo demas lo puedo hacer pero esa  es mi duda que necesito el username y la img de perfil en cada fila, pero para las dos cosas comentarios y respuestas, mas claro que eso no creo que pueda explicarlo amigo.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [MYSQL retorna filas repetidas cuando hago SELECT de tablas relacionadas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239896/mysql-retorna-filas-repetidas-cuando-hago-select-de-tablas-relacionadas)